# Fixing number with commas

Tags: python

I've been learning python for a couple days and trying to work through an easy project.

```
income = int(input("please write your families' yearly income \n"))

if(income <= 30000):
```

I want the program to fix the syntax errors if it contains a comma, dot, or a space between, like 20.000, 20,000, and 20 0000. What should I do?

Also, can I mean thousands by seperating digits with a comma? Writing `if(income <= 30,000):` to mean thirty thousand, for instance.

I couldn't find anything to solving it. Checked the try except blocks, but I don't think its the right thing for fixing this.

Comment: You'll need to do something like take the string from `input` without calling `int` on it, use something like `replace` to remove the characters that you don't want, *then* take that new standardized string and give that to `int`.

Comment: You can use an underscore to space up long numbers, e.g., `30_000`.